# Multisite - Display different header content based on which site is accessed

Tags: php, customization, html, links

I currently have multisite enabled for a project, with three websites in the build. I made some customizations to header.php (I'm using a child theme). I hardcoded a link into the header, and it worked fine, but now I need the link to be different for each of the sites. Is there a way I can display a different line of html based on which of the three sites in my multisite is accessed? Here's a snippet from my header.php, in case it helps to get a better visual:

`<div class="added-header"><a href="http://example.com/example-page/my-account/">CUSTOMER LOGIN</a></div>`

This code is placed in between blocks of PHP code, so I can easily add PHP to make this work. I'm using the Divi theme, FYI.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use options to customize this for every site. Options are stored separately for each site.

So, inside your header you can do something like

`<?php
$login_link = get_option("worduoso_login_link");
$login_text = get_option("worduoso_login_text");
?>`

and then print it like this

`<?php if($login_link && $login_text): ?>
<div class="added-header"><a href="<?php echo $login_link; ?>"><?php echo $login_text; ?></a></div><?php endif; ?>`

So, how do you set this option?

If you want to add it just once you can just execute this code:

`<?php 
add_option( 'worduoso_login_link', 'http://www.example.com/login', '', 'yes' );
add_option( 'worduoso_login_text', 'Customer Login', '', 'yes' );
?>`

(add code to functions.php and call the correct site, repeat for each site)

Better way is to add a section to theme customizer where those will be shown to admin under Appearance->Customize in WP admin. This is a bit more advanced code, here is the gist with 2 pieces - once to include in functions.php and one to include in header.php: https://gist.github.com/worduoso/9439aee7c5b91380527a06ac17498d41